# Auto Filter or sort by date

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I'm trying to create a copy of a worksheet and sort or filter by the date. I would like it by the current date but when I have it as filter, it removes all data with the current date. I really only want to see those rows with the current date. This is the code I have so far.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Copy

    Range("A1:Q1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("C2").Select

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:V80000").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="<" & Date
```

Comment: maybe `"=" & Date` .  What you have is filtering those less than current Date.

Comment: Great! if you can accept my ansewr below

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:V80000").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="<" & Date
```

To

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:V80000").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="=" & Date
```